Quadratic Eigenvalue Problem
Is SLEPc really the only C/C++ package that provides a solver for the Quadratic Eigenvalue Problem (QEP) out of the box, using sparse matrices?

Is there a particular reason why SLEPc does not work for you?

@AntonMenshov steep learning curve. Even fill a matrix is not a straightforward task.

SLEPc works on top of PETSc, which has a million example programs on how to fill matrices. That surely can't be a good reason.

@WolfgangBangerth, fill matrices is just an example of the steep learning curve of it.

I don't know of any other ones, but on the other hand it is easy to convert a QEP to a standard (or generalized) eigenvalue problem by linearization, preserving sparsity. So it makes sense that there is not much incentive to implement and maintain a specific solver for this problem, when it can be easily converted to another more common primitive.

Could you show how to perform these conversions and recommend other C++ packages?

@PonyboyCurtis See, for instance, section 2 of https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/Winter09/qep.pdf .

+1 @PonyboyCurtis Pay attention to the SOAR algorithm mentioned in Bai's notes as this procedure preserves the second order structure. This is something that can be lost by linearization.
